# R - How can I insert a new column in a dataset that will cross match with a lookup table?

Tags: r, dplyr, lookup

I'm trying to add a new column to a dataset (worktable) that will do the equivalent of an Excel vlookup. I need the new column to find which courtname in worktable match that of the court in the lookup table and flag the ones that correspond **and** have data in any one of three columns (‘drreqt’, ‘atrreqt’, and ‘mhtrreqt’) in the worktable (i.e. they aren't all empty).

I've tried using mutate functions to add the new column and know that a case_when function will probably work best. I had this so far just to flag when there was a match but it hasn't worked:

```
mutate(worktable$court_match = case_when(lookup$court = worktable$courtname ~'Match', TRUE ~ 'No Match'))
```

Any ideas I would be really grateful!!:)

Comment: You could do a join or merge. i.e. `left_join(worktable, lookup, by = c("court_name" = "court")`

Comment: If you need more help, please provide a small reproducible example. You can use `dput()` to generate R code for an object including all class information, e.g., `dput(worktable[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows.

Comment: @akrun Getting the following error: 
> left_join(worktable, lookup, by = c("court_name" = "court"))
Error in left_join(worktable, lookup, by = c(court_name = "court")) : 
  could not find function "left_join"

Comment: It is in dplyr `library(dplyr)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your idea is solid. You just need == instead of =
Here is an example with sample data since you did not provide a dataset.

```
worktable <- data.frame(courtname = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
                                      1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))

lookup <- data.frame(court = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 
                               1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))


df <- worktable %>% 
mutate(court_match = case_when(
  lookup$court == worktable$courtname ~ 'Match', 
  TRUE ~ 'No Match'))
```

[image: sample]